# How to determine the number of worker processes

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm following along with a tutorial for setting up nginx on ubuntu. I have nginx installed and it started successfully. The tutorial says this about adjusting and setting nginx processes and worker connections

```
It is often recommended to set the number of NGINX workers equal the number of processors, you can determine the number of processors using:

cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
```

When I run the command, I got a 0.

```
processor   : 0
```

Therefore, according to the tutorial, I should set the config to 0 in the appropriate location

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


worker_processes 0;
```

The tutorial's example has a 1. However, I was a little concerned not only about seeing a 0 when I ran the output, but also when I ran `ps -ef | grep nginx`, I got this output, suggesting there are multiple workprocesses?

```
root      1824     1  0 19:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbinnginx
www-data  1825  1824  0 19:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1826  1824  0 19:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1827  1824  0 19:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1828  1824  0 19:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
michael   1832  1378  0 19:44 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Is it a matter for concern that I see a 0 when I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor` and what should I set `worker_processes 0;` to in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Comment: HI there, I'm doing a Nginx installation and I see 4 worker process as well. Should I limit them to one or is it fine? I'm assuming that the less I touch the configuration the easier is to mantain it. What do you reckon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the counting starts from `0`, so only getting a `processor : 0` means you only have 1 processor/core.

I am not sure but I'm assuming `worker_processes 0;` means unlimited, so I think you should change it to `worker_processes 1`, if you want it to be corresponding to the number of processors you have;